# Spyder launches the wrong Python Version

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, environment

I've configured the following Anaconda environment:

```
conda create --name pix2pix python==3.5
...
activate pix2pix    
pip install spyder
```

If I start spyder in this environment by `start spyder`, it launches Python 3.7 and not 3.5. Moreover, the Anaconda Navigator says that Spyder is not installed in this environment. However, the Anaconda Prompt says it is when typing `pip list`.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: On which OS are you? Uninstall spyder with pip, and reinstall it using conda (`conda install spyder`).

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Your last line is wrong: `pip install spyder`. You don't need it because a) Spyder comes with Anaconda, so you really need to do `conda install spyder` (conda and pip are not interchangeable); and b) that line probably broke your Anaconda installation, so I'm afraid you'll have to reinstall and try again (that's a side effect of "conda and pip are not interchangeable").

Answer (score 1):

[Carlos Cordoba's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267170/spyder-launches-the-wrong-python-version/53280111#comment93426264_53267170) solved my problem:

> Your last line is wrong: `pip install spyder`. You don't need it because a) Spyder comes with Anaconda, so you really need to do `conda install spyder` (conda and pip are not interchangeable); and b) that line probably broke your Anaconda installation, so I'm afraid you'll have to reinstall and try again (that's a side effect of "conda and pip are not interchangeable").

Instead of `pip install spyder`, I used `conda install spyder`.